# Deploying mutliple chaincode files with the NodeSDK

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have a running hyperledger fabric application. It works fine when deploying one chaincode file (.go file) .I can `Query` and `Invoke`it fine. I made a new chaincode and put this in my path. It doesn't give me any issues when deploying but It also doesn't return two chaincode hashes.

I'm deploying the chaincode as follows:

```
            var req = {
                fcn: "init",
                args: [],
                chaincodePath: chaincodePath 
            };
            var dply = admin.deploy(req);
```

The deployment is always successful but I get only one hash.
What am I doing wrong? Is this possible? if not how can you deploy multiple chaincode files (.go) at the same time

Comment: Each deploy transaction will deploy 1 chaincode and a hash value used to reference that chaincode in deploy and invoke txs.

So to deploy two chaincodes or the same chaincode twice, you need to make two txs.

Comment: Would u mind sharing ur code to deploying the blockchain using node sdk? I'm having some trouble to do it

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini Is your issue similar to mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768283/hfc-cc-deployment-successfull-while-peer-error-building-images . Maybe you have already solved it?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini Sorry for the late response, but I don't have the code anymore. I'm currently also not working on hyperledger. But I do remember that I used the node SDK

Comment: I've fixed here, following https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/fabric-boilerplate code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every chaincode should be in a single directory and deployed one by one.