# HFC: CC deployment successfull while PEER: "Error building images: ..."

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

**TL;DR; Go to ---- EDIT section below**

I am using **`hfc@0.6.5`** in a standalone node.js application.

A membersrvc and peer are started with `docker-compose`, where:

```
membersrvc:
  container_name: membersrvc
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc:latest
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  container_name: peer
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
    - "7051:7051"
    - "7053:7053"
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=172.17.0.2:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=172.17.0.2:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=172.17.0.2:7054
    - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=noops
[...]
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 10; peer node start"
```

The node.js application successfully registers new users and tries to deploy a chaincode using the `enrolledUser.deploy(deployRequest);` method.

As a value of `deployRequest.chaincodePath` a path
`'github.com/asset-chaincode/'` is set.The directory contains a chaincode `.go` file.

A callback of `deployTx.on('complete', cb)` prints its log message:

```
SUCCESS: Successfully deployed chaincode [chainCodeId:415123c8532fd28393d7a5370193af555e9f2141a4b56e635806e5e1fcce1e58], deploy request={"fcn":"init","args":[],"confidential":true,"metadata":{"type":"Buffer","data":[48,...155,253,0]},"chaincodePath":"github.com/gvlax/chaincodes/asset-chaincode"}, response={"uuid":"415123c8532fd28393d7a5370193af555e9f2141a4b56e635806e5e1fcce1e58","chaincodeID":"415123c8532fd28393d7a5370193af555e9f2141a4b56e635806e5e1fcce1e58"}
chaincodeId=415123c8532fd28393d7a5370193af555e9f2141a4b56e635806e5e1fcce1e58
```

However, when I check an output of a peer console, 
I can see error messages

--> [**full logs here**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gvlax/chaincodes/master/peer-errors.txt):

```
        peer       | 15:40:00.416 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 47a Error building images: The command '/bin/sh -c go install build-chaincode && cp src/build-chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin && mv $GOPATH/bin/build-chaincode $GOPATH/bin/23991376d1b935790631a448843fd12a9d60f7ab3f0b8b55f629cf0190077436' returned a non-zero code: 1
    [...]    
        peer       |  ---> Running in 812439684bf7
        peer       | src/build-chaincode/asset-chaincode.go:25:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
        peer       |    /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOROOT)
        peer       |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOPATH)
        peer       | src/build-chaincode/asset-chaincode.go:26:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/primitives" in any of:
        peer       |    /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/primitives (from $GOROOT)
        peer       |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/primitives (from $GOPATH)
        peer       | package build-chaincode
        peer       |    imports github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging: must be imported as github.com/op/go-logging
    [...]
```

It looks like there are some issues not exactly related to the chaincode compilation on the peer. 
Or the chaincode is deployed to a location on the peer where relative import paths in the chaincode cannot be resolved ....

### **---- EDIT (some hours later)**

After many attempts and experiments, I think my problem is always the same:
Regardless of any valid chaincode (stored locally in a directory `$GOPATH/src/gibhub.com/<mychaincode_dir>` + building with no errors) after being deployed on a peer with the method `enrolledUser.deploy(deployRequest)` (hfc@0.6.5), a result gives always the same errors on the target node:

```
peer       | Step 4 : RUN go install build-chaincode && cp src/build-chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin && mv $GOPATH/bin/build-chaincode $GOPATH/bin/0881d0fe8f4528e1369bfe917cd207d919a07758cc098e212ca74f6766c636d4
peer       |  ---> Running in b0ca2abbe609
peer       | src/build-chaincode/asset-chaincode.go:25:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
peer       |    /opt/gopath/src/build-chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (vendor tree)
peer       |    /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOROOT)
```

The imports of the cc the peer complains about are:

```
import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    [...]
```

moreover, when I go to the peer CLI, the shim can be found there ...

```
$ docker exec -it peer bash
$ find / -name shim
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
$ echo $GOPATH/
/opt/gopath/
```

Isn't something wrong with the fabric-peer image ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy with hfc, you need to "vendor" the fabric chaincode packages  - see http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/nodeSDK/node-sdk-indepth/#chaincode-deployment

You can also have a look at https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/SDK-Demo/tree/master/src/chaincode for an example of doing this with the SDK as well

Comment: Thanks again, Gari. I think this is a good example how it should look in practise: https://github.com/ratnakar-asara/hello-blockchain